# Inline list elements, add numbering overlay

Tags: jquery, html, css, image-gallery

I wrote [this thumbnails gallery](http://iloop.it/custom.asp) using jquery lightbox plugin years ago.

```
<div class="p">
    <ul class="gallery">
        <li><a rel="lightbox-gallery" href="..."><img src="..."></a></li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>

div.p {
    text-align: justify;
}

.gallery li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Maybe it's not perfect but it spaces evenly on the whole column width and self adapts itself on window resize.

Now pics are nearly 40 and I'd like to add **with jquery** a little overlay with photo number, something like this:

[image: example]

but I'm having some trouble since elements are inline and not block.

Is it possible to achieve it **without** changing base style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: absolute;` will do the trick. The `<li>` needs to be `position: relative`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/gH7vH/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a><img class="thumbnail" /></a><div class="number">1</div></li>
    <li><a><img class="thumbnail" /></a><div class="number">2</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail
{
    border: 1px solid black; 
    display: inline-block;   
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
li
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.number
{
    background-color: rgba( 47, 47, 47, .3);
    bottom: 0;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 18px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I was playing with `inline-block` but is it crossbrowser solid?

Comment: I think IE has some problems with `inline-block`, but don't remember if is only on quirks mode

Comment: `inline-block` is fine in all browsers. It's not a requirement for this to work though. Just `position: absolute;` on the number and `position: relative;` on the `li`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [position plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) of jQueryUI. It can help you do this.

Answer (score 1):

In [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/WJhyQ/), I added this bit of code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.gallery').find('a').each(function(i){
        $(this).append('<div class="number">' + (i+1) + '</div>')
    });
});
```

and this css

```
.gallery .number {
    background: #eee;
    color: #000;
    min-width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 3px;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
.gallery a {
    position: relative;
}
```

Edit: Oops, you can just add the `i+1` to the demo...

Comment: This is really what I was looking for. I think I played with `.gallery a { position: relative }` but with no luck, now wonder what I did wrong... thanks. Just hope I can fix portrait images (#9, #10)

Comment: Nope, I'm having the same troubles as when I tried getting it to work: a [demo page here](http://iloop.it/custom_numbered.asp) shows the problem.